# AWS Serverless API Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless, amazon-iam, aws-serverless

Whenever I begin to use the AWS_IAM authorizer on my function, my API GET request - which is being made from a web client - receives a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` and I'm getting a 403 status code. When I remove the aws_iam authorizer, the API request - made via the same web client - succeeds. So I'm pretty sure it's not actually a CORS error since I've double checked that my API has cors enabled. I'm not sure if I'm using the AWS Javascript SDK wrong or if I'm not generating proper roles for AWS_IAM in my serverless.yml config.

When I run the request from postman with my personal access keys from AWS, the request succeeds. When I console.log the keys from the AWS.config.credentials and use those in postman, the request receives an invalid token error message. Maybe I haven't generated the proper role for my federated identity pool?

I'm using aws4 on the front-end to sign the request, and I use axios to make the request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Axios will make a pre-flight request. It's an `OPTIONS` type and expects a 200 response before it will make the `GET` request. It also needs to return the CORS header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Postman won't make the same call automatically but you can use it to test that request. Ensure that your API is accepting `OPTIONS` request methods for that route and that it returns an empty 200 response with the CORS header and I think you'll be good to go.

AFAIK, the `OPTIONS` request needn't be authenticated. Just give a green light. It may be the case that your client is making calls to this endpoint as OPTIONS requests that are being authenticated, adding a second layer of confusion, or you may need to add an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to allow an `Authorisation` type header if AWS is using one.

Hard to give more information without debugging but I would start with an `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: The OPTIONS request seems to succeed with proper response. I am beginning to believe there is an issue with my AWS Federated Identity being granted access to my API Gateway.

Comment: Hmm. What headers are you sending along to authenticate via postman? Are they included in the allowed headers CORS rule? Or is the authentication not being required for the OPTIONS req?

Comment: Authentication isn't required for the OPTIONS request.